# Searching user by username?

Tags: firebase, flutter, search, google-cloud-firestore

Im trying to search user by username but getting an error maybe anyone can help.
I wanna search like this

```
class MyprofilTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final myprofil profile;
  

  Future getusers()async{
    var firestore= FirebaseFirestore.instance;
   QuerySnapshot qn = await  firestore.collection('meinprofilsettings').get();
return qn.docs.where((p) => p.startsWith(query)).toList();
  }

  MyprofilTile({this.profile});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child:FutureBuilder(
        future:getusers(),
        builder: (_,snapshot){
        if(snapshot.connectionState ==ConnectionState.waiting){
          return  Center(
              child: Container(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
            );
        }else{
          return ListView.builder(itemCount: snapshot.data.length, itemBuilder: (_,index){
          return ListTile(
          title:Text(snapshot.data[index].data()['username']),
          );
      }
      );
```

So in the  Future method above this im trying to search and here I returning this whole class

```
class DataSearch extends SearchDelegate<String> {
  @override
  List<Widget> buildActions(BuildContext context) {
    // actions fro app bar
    return [IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.clear), onPressed: () {query = "";

    },),];
  }

  @override
  Widget buildLeading(BuildContext context) {
    // leading icon on the left of the app bar
    return IconButton(
        icon: AnimatedIcon(
          icon: AnimatedIcons.menu_arrow,
          progress: transitionAnimation,
        ),
        onPressed: () {
          close(context, null);});
  }

  @override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
    // show some result based on the selection
    return Container();
  }

  @override
  Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context,{String url, username, email, uid, receiperid}) {
    // show when someone searches for something
    return MyprofilTile();
  }
}
```

What I want is that if user like tap S getting all users that the first letter is S and then tap Sp getting all users where first 2 letters of  name contains with Sp and so on. And also react of uppercases . So it should be irellevant if user tap S or s.

The error is this : The method 'startsWith' isn't defined for the type documetnsnapshot . And also undefined name query ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to search in the attribut username not in whole doc

```
  Future getusers()async{
    var firestore= FirebaseFirestore.instance;
   QuerySnapshot qn = await  firestore.collection('meinprofilsettings').get();
return qn.docs.where((p) => p.data()['username'].toString().startsWith(query)).toList();
  }
```

update your constructor

```
class MyprofilTile extends StatelessWidget { 
    final myprofil profile; final String query; // add this 
    MyprofilTile({this.query}`); //update this`
```

and in your `class DataSearch`

```
@override
  Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context,{String url, username, email, uid, receiperid}) {
    // show when someone searches for something
    return MyprofilTile(query: query);
  }
```

Comment: Yes that make sense but still one error name query ist defined

Comment: Ok I think query will be fixed by Query but it made not being the right place for this method because it says the getter length was called on null .What do you think ?

Comment: No it says query isn't defined .. Please check my comments what do you think ?

Comment: What you you mean? I mean if I use 'Query' instead of 'query' in your first solution im getting no errors just this error The getter length was called on null

Comment: where youre declaring String query that you pass to your startwith()

Comment: Nowhere I can use this query inside my buildsugesstion method but maybe I should declared in my class MyprofilTile class to used there  ?

Comment: Yes that was it but do you know how to do this with the uppercases and lowercases ?

Comment: if it works please set an up vote, you can create another question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230673/discussion-between-anna-and-usinguser).